# How to do RakNet Keep-Alive

Tags: c++, network-programming, multiplayer, raknet

I'm planning my server loop for a simple networked game I want to make.

Using RakPeerInterface (which sounds like a reliable UDP implementation from what I've read), I want to be able to tell, within 3 seconds, if a player has disconnected from the game through unexpected means (client crash, disconnect, task-manager-terminate).

I think there is a raknet feature somewhere that does exactly this, but I haven't found it yet.

Comment: I've never used Raknet so can't mention any specific features however one solution would be to increase the rate at which the server pings connected clients assuming this is possible in Raknet.

Comment: thanks for replying! :) yeah I know that almost every method of 'keep alive' is a variation of spamming reliable packets, I meant to ask if the RakNet framework had a built-in way to do it so I don't reinvent the wheel.